# meteor android crosswalk twitter login

Tags: android, authentication, meteor, twitter, crosswalk

This works fine for chrome on android, however as an android app, the login does not return after authenticating.

A window is provided which hangs unless one aborts. Perhaps some addtional permission are needed ?

The most simple test using meteor create etc also ends in the same way,
works ok on chrome/android , yet fails as an app on android.

Comment: maybe the callback url must be changed to localhost ? as that is where the client code resides .

Answer (score 0):

yes, for the apk meteor android app to work, the callback url must be changed,to 127.0.0.1. So the chrome solution must be a separate system
, which uses the remotehost callback.

Comment: most of the time  the callback hack will NOT work leaving it impossible to login on the android app !!